# Apply css to all ids using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

all

I want to show hide some ids using jQuery.
My html code is

```
<table>
<tr id="incomplete"></tr>
<tr id="complete"></tr>
<tr id="incomplete"></tr>
<tr id="incomplete"></tr>
<tr id="complete"></tr>
</table>
```

and jquery code is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
          jQuery(document).ready(function () {
                          jQuery("#button-entryc").click(function() {


                          jQuery("#incomplete").css("display","none");
                          jQuery("#complete").css("display","table-row");
                      });

                      jQuery("#button-entryi").click(function() {

                          jQuery("#incomplete").css("display","table-row");
                          jQuery("#complete").css("display","none");
                      });
              });
    </script>
```

But it works for only on id (first id which it finds) Why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[IDs must be unique](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#adef-id), what you can do is use the [class attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#adef-class) and change your `#` to a `.`

e.g.

```
<tr class="incomplete"></tr>
$('.incomplete')
```

Comment: yes, it should be a class if it's applied to mulitple elements

Answer (score 1):

The concept of IDs is to only use them once (so you can refer to one single object). If you want some rules to apply to several elements use classes instead.

Select a class in jQuery by adding the `.`, just like in CSS:

```
$('.myClass').click(function(){$(this).css('color','red');});
```

See: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_id_class.asp for example